# Php shows wrong time

Tags: php

I'm making a website and the php time is incorrect, it is 40 seconds behinde. How do I fix it? (I have time events on my site). I have one javascript clock which is fine btw.

Comment: php shows server time.

Comment: Javascript runs on the client-side and gets the time from your computer's clock.

Comment: well seems you server clock and client clock have two different time  .. is tipcal with two clock..

Comment: @Mathias Bakkerjord Since you know that there is a 40 Seconds difference between JS and PHP Clock-Times (probably because the Server Clock & the Clock of your Local Machine are not in Sync); why not add the 40 Seconds difference either to the JS or to PHP? That way you simulate a Sync between the 2.

Comment: use ntpdate on the server to update the OS clock

Answer (score 2):

The time that PHP used is depend on Your host server.

get time with javascript shows you your client time.

its better to ask the hosting team to correct server time.